# Better way to write this code in functional manner using map and reduce?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have an array of items on which I have to perform 2 tasks:

1. Applying  a function on the array item
2. Checking if the value is true or false.

The functional approach to solving this would be

```
var result = arr.map(function(item){return some_action(item);}).filter(function(item){return other_action(item) == true;});
```

But here the array `arr` is traversed twice in comparison to

```
var result = [];
arr.forEach(function(item){
    var x = other_action(some_action(item));
    if (x)
        result.push(x);
});
```

Isn't the functional approach bad in this case or am I not using `map` and `filter` the right way?

Answer (score 8):

Your “functional” approach is overly complicated. Notice that this is completely equivalent:

```
var result = arr.map(some_action).filter(other_action);
```

I.e. If you're only delegating to another function, you can specify that function directly. Also, an `== true` test is superfluous.

Your “procedural” variant is not equivalent, that would have to be:

```
var result = [];
arr.forEach(function(item){
    var changedItem = some_action(item);
    if (other_action(changedItem))
        result.push(changedItem);
});
```

Note that both variants have the same *algorithmic complexity*, and that the cost of iteration is likely negligible compared with the cost of `some_action` and `other_action`.

Functional programming does not mean unreadable code. Even if you're not just delegating to another function, you could improve formatting, e.g. to

```
var result = arr.map(function (item) {
  return some_action(item);
}).filter(function (item) {
  return other_action(item);
});
```

Comment: sorry i mistyped the procedural version

Answer (score 5):

Your loops are not equivalent. In the first one `result` will be `arr` mapped with some action, while in the second you could do that just using a filter.

The equivalent way of writing the `forEach` loop would be to use `result.push(some_action(item))`. Of course you would cache it as you use `some_action(item)` earlier in the function.

The equivalent way of writing your `forEach` loop with just `filter` would be

```
arr.filter(function(item){return other_action(some_action(item));});
```

Also, as this is code review I would like to point out you can probably write

```
arr.map(function(item){return some_action(item);})
```

As

```
arr.map(some_action) //note this is not equivalent if some_action can take multiple params.
```

Anyway, you are correct in that calling these loop methods will take `O(n)` time per call and it's a good idea to apply filters first to limit `n`. If you're looking for an interesting read take a look at the [Lazy.js documentation](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/).

**Edit**, just noticed, because you mention reduce, the way you'd write this with reduce is akin to you `forEach` way

```
arr.reduce(function(result, item){
    var item = other_action(some_action(item));
    if (item) result.push(item);
    return result;
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't do this:

```
 var result = arr.map(function(item){
          var result=some_action(item);
          if(other_action(result)){  
             return result;
          }
  });
```

if other_action() return false, the item position in array will be undefined.

Comment: When `other_action(result)` is falsy the mapped value will be undefined which is not desired. `$.map` will allow you to do that though

Comment: you are right. I am not aware of it. thanks.